# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float (PySimpleGUI)

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo a usar PySimpleGUI y estoy teniendo un problema en la linea donde estoy usando un for,
se supone que deberia acceder a cada key(n(n)_salida) de la ventana y cambiar su valor por los de la lista nota_algebra, mas que nada lo que quiero hacer es simplificar un poco el codigo.

realmente nose si se podra hacer lo que yo estoy haciendo o si es un error de novato.

este es el error que se esta generando

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\salva\PycharmProjects\pysimplegui\appEjemplo3.py", line 55, in <module>
    ventana[reemplazo].update(notas_algebra[n])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float


import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkAmber")

notas_poo = [6.6,None,None,None,None,None,None]
notas_diseño = [3.9,7,None,None,None,None,None]
notas_algebra = [4.9,0,0,0,0,0,0]

disenio = [
   [sg.Text("Nombre: "), sg.Input(key="nombre_entrada")],
   [sg.Text("Apellido: "), sg.Input(key="apellido_entrada")],
   [sg.Text("Asignatura: "), sg.Input(key="asignatura_entrada")],
   [sg.Button("Mostrar"), sg.Button("Salir")],
   [sg.Frame("Informacion",layout=[
        [sg.Text("Asignatura: "), sg.Text(size=(40,1),key="asignatura_salida")],
        [sg.Text("Notas: "),
            sg.Text("N1: ", key='n1_salida'),
            sg.Text("N2: ", key='n2_salida'),
            sg.Text("N3: ", key='n3_salida'),
            sg.Text("N4: ", key='n4_salida'),
            sg.Text("N5: ", key='n5_salida'),
            sg.Text("N6: ", key='n6_salida'),
            sg.Text("N7: ", key='n7_salida'),
         ]

    ])]
]


ventana = sg.Window("Ventana",disenio)

while True:
   event, value = ventana.read()

   if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Salir":
      break

   if(event == "Mostrar"):
      if value["asignatura_entrada"] == "POO":
        ventana["asignatura_salida"].update(value["asignatura_entrada"])
        ventana["n1_salida"].update(notas_poo[0])
        ventana["n2_salida"].update(notas_poo[1])
        ventana["n3_salida"].update(notas_poo[2])
      elif value["asignatura_entrada"] == "Diseño de Software":
        ventana["asignatura_salida"].update(value["asignatura_entrada"])
        ventana["n1_salida"].update(notas_diseño[0])
        ventana["n2_salida"].update(notas_diseño[1])
        ventana["n3_salida"].update(notas_diseño[2])
      elif value["asignatura_entrada"] == "Algebra":
        ventana["asignatura_salida"].update(value["asignatura_entrada"])
        i = 1
        for n in notas_algebra:
            reemplazo = "n"+str(i)+"_salida"
            print(reemplazo)
            ventana[reemplazo].update(notas_algebra[n])
            i += 1


ventana.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo estaba haciendo mal

yo lo que hacia en el `.update(notas_algebra[n])` era pasarle una nota que se almacenaba en la variable n, entonces nunca iba a encontrar el dato ya que la primera nota de la lista es un valor flotante y no un indice y me lanzaba error por eso.

```
    i = 1
    for n in notas_algebra:
        reemplazo = "n"+str(i)+"_salida"
        print(reemplazo)
        ventana[reemplazo].update(notas_algebra[n])
        i += 1
```

y lo que tenia que hacer es pasarle `i-1` para que me sacara la nota de la lista y se reemplazara `n(n)_salida`

```
    for i in range(1,len(notas_db)):
        ventana["n"+str(i)+"_salida"].update(notas_db[i-1])
```